# How to filter the particular span class by BS4 of a wikipedia page?

Tags: python-3.x, wikipedia, beautifulsoup

This [Wikipedia page](https://ta.wikipedia.org/s/h6h) contains two reference errors. You can find the reference errors as red sentences (reference serial number 6 and 95) just above at the bottom of the page.When i inspect the element, i find that i should extract the particular span class namely `<span class="error mw-ext-cite-error"`How can i get the copy of the outer html of `<span class="error mw-ext-cite-error`" data?

The following code gives all the `<span class>` data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

getUrl= 'https://ta.wikipedia.org/s/h6h' 
url = getUrl
content = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
heading = soup.title
print(heading.text)
#to get the specific li-interwiki-ta tag<span class="error mw-ext-cite-error" 
refError = soup.findAll ('span')
print (refError)
```

how can i filter and get that the particular `<span class="error mw-ext-cite-error` data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the particular class and iterate over the elements by:

```
refError = soup.findAll('span', { 'class': 'mw-ext-cite-error'})
for error in refError:
    print error
```